# Error while executing IECleanAnchorsFilters - RegExpError; Expected quantifier

Tags: asp.net, telerik, text-editor

I am getting an error in `telerik rad editor`.

The error is

> Error while executing  IECleanAnchorsFilters - RegExpError; Expected quantifier

Can anyone suggest an answer which does not involve updating telerik?

Comment: RadEditor1.EnableFilter(EditorFilters.None) done the trick

Comment: but could not found any specific reason why it occurs and how it stopped by this solution. In teleric forum it says once you upgrade this will not be happens.

Answer (score 0):

Added simple line on page load and in all `RadEditors`

```
RadEditor1.EnableFilter(EditorFilters.None)
```

Comment: Did this solve your problem? It's unclear if it did or not. If it did answer it, please try to explain a bit about why it worked, for anyone else that might come across this problem in future.